# JavaScript widget not showing up on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to add a widget to a website but it doesn't show up in the preview, in Visual mode it shows a script icon, but there's nothing to be seen. The code is:

```html
'<div id="pb-widget-xxxx"  style="height: 600px"></div>

<script src="http://cloud.photoboothsolutions.com/js/photobooth-manager.js"></script>
<script>
  PhotoBooth.initWidget('pb-widget-xxxx', 'xxxx','http://cloud.photoboothsolutions.com');
</script>'
```

EDIT: 
I get those Console errors:
Mixed Content: 
The page at 'https://photosnacks.ro/get-your-photo/?preview_id=1753&preview_nonce=abad8a0d22&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script http://cloud.photoboothsolutions.com/js/photobooth-manager.js'.
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

photosnacks.ro/:2003
 Uncaught ReferenceError: 'PhotoBooth is not defined
    at photosnacks.ro/

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]

```
at Function.fa.error (jquery.js:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.js:2)
at fa.compile (jquery.js:2)
at jquery.js:2
at PSEUDO (jquery.js:2)
at wa (jquery.js:2)
at fa.compile (jquery.js:2)
at fa.select (jquery.js:2)
at Function.fa (jquery.js:2)
at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Any errors in your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when you load the page?

Comment: (if so, please add that information to the question, not as a comment)

Comment: Seems like there's something with the site considering http as insecure?